# SelectedIndexChanged event of dropdownlist in Listview not happening. in a usercontrol

Tags: selectedindexchanged

I have a ListView and DropDownList(primary) and tow more and a text box, inside  every Row of that ListView. All on a user control ,and using the this user control on the other usercontol(here the operations to be performed.)(we are using DNN) .
 Now I would like to add event handler for dropdownlist which would react on SelectedIndexChanged. I wanted to show and hide the other dropdowns and textbox depending on a specific value of the DropDrownList(primary) selected.
I am nowhere to do the same..despite the several attempts.

**Screening Outcome:&nbsp**
                                
                                
                                   
                                
                                
                                    Comments:
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Subset Used:&nbsp
                                
                                
                                    
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    **TAR Status:&nbsp**

code behind like this

Public Sub ddlFindingsScreeningOutcome_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
            Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)

```
        Dim item As ListViewItem = CType(ddl.NamingContainer, ListViewItem)

        Dim txtFindingsComments As TextBox = CType(item.FindControl("txtFindingsComments"), TextBox)
        Dim ddlFindingsTarStatus As DropDownList = CType(item.FindControl("ddlFindingsTarStatus"), DropDownList)

        If Not ddl Is Nothing Then
            If Not ddl.SelectedItem.Text = "Not Screened" Then
                txtFindingsComments.Visible = True
                ddlFindingsTarStatus.Visible = True

            End If
        Else
            txtFindingsComments.Visible = False
            ddlFindingsTarStatus.Visible = False
        End If


    End Sub
```